# IBM Filenet IS: Retrieval Cache is full w/documents whose page = 65535

Tags: filenet, filenet-image-services

I am relatively new to FileNet Image Services. I am coming into an existing development environment where FileNet Image Services 4.2x is set up for test purposes. As I understand it, we have a 'cache-only' installation. Before last weekend, the retrieval cache was running around 73% full (10GB cache).

The Retrieval cache filled up last weekend. Upon investigating, I found that there were thousands of documents (all of the same size, 80312kb) with a page = 65535. I have yet to discover the source of these documents, but the immediate issue is:

***How do I remove/delete these documents from the cache and free up the space used by them?***

fyi...I tried deldocs according to the user documentation, but it would not remove these documents. I was able to remove other documents successfully with deldocs.

Note: adding to the Retrieval cache is not an option because of a limitation on disk space. I have scoured the documentation but cannot find any help there...apologies if this is a rudimentary problem.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the [Filenet Image Services 4.2 System Tools Reference Manual](http://www-05.ibm.com/e-business/linkweb/publications/servlet/pbi.wss?CTY=US&FNC=SRX&PBL=SC19-3326-00#)

The `deldocs` command doesn't always suit you because

> The deldocs tool deletes documents from the Image Services index
>   database and/or the MKF permanent database. It could also delete
>   selected documents from cache, given selected settings

Some documents could be in **locked** or **ageable** status.

So if you already tried with this command and haved no results you should go for the `CSM_tool` command.

You will find this tool on page 206, it will allow you to inspect your installation's cache.

Next issue a `Listobjects` command to see what's going on in there and have a representation of the single document cache status.

Then take a look to the `DELETEobjects` command, which allows you to delete cache entries by id.

**CAUTION: this command, as stated in the documentation, can harm your system so pay attention about what you're doing.** To issue this command you will be required to previously launch the ALLOWUPDATEs command, that ask you for username and password in order to modify the cache.
Remember that as reported in the docs:

> When listing CSM_tool commands, some might not appear if you have
>   not run the ALLOWUPDATES command. To list password-protected
>   commands, you must first run ALLOWUPDATES.

You will be also asked to confirm every action and a report of the operation will be logged into specific files stored in folders dependent on your environment.